# A python non finished function

Tags: python, function

So I have to make a function with returns a list from n to 1 where n will be divided by 2 and added to a list, then the number with was divided by 2 will be multiplied by 3 and will be summed up by 1. This will naturally go on until it reaches the number 1.
The code I have so far:

```
def Gaus(n):
    list = []
    if n%2 == 0:
        list.append(n/2)
    else:
        list.append((n*3)+1)
    return list
```

So Gaus(30) should return:
[15,46,23,70....,2]

I'm new here at stack overflow, so sorry if my way of asking things is not clear enough. Thank you!

Comment: Ask new question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly ... this is a recursive implementation:

```
def gaus(n, ls = list()):
    if n == 1:
        return ls
    else:
        ls.append(n / 2.)           # Step 1:  n / 2
        ls.append(ls[-1] * 3 + 1)   # Step 2: (n / 2) * 3 + 1
        return gaus(n - 1, ls)

print gaus(30)
```

The result is this list:

```
[15.0, 46.0, 14.5, 44.5, 14.0, 43.0, 13.5, 41.5, 13.0, 40.0, 12.5, 38.5, 12.0, 37.0, 11.5, 35.5, 11.0, 34.0, 10.5, 32.5, 10.0, 31.0, 9.5, 29.5, 9.0, 28.0, 8.5, 26.5, 8.0, 25.0, 7.5, 23.5, 7.0, 22.0, 6.5, 20.5, 6.0, 19.0, 5.5, 17.5, 5.0, 16.0, 4.5, 14.5, 4.0, 13.0, 3.5, 11.5, 3.0, 10.0, 2.5, 8.5, 2.0, 7.0, 1.5, 5.5, 1.0, 4.0]
```

---

**Edit**:

```
def print_gaus(n):
    if n == 1:
        return
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            print (n / 2),
            print (n / 2 * 3 + 1),
            print_gaus(n / 2 * 3 + 1)
        print_gaus(n - 1)

print print_gaus(30)
```

But notice, it will break because of the maximum recursion depth of your environment.

Comment: This is almost how it should be, everytime that the number is even it should return  that number divided by two, so 46/2 = 23 instead of the 14.5. And the number 23 should be multiplied by 3 and summed up by one like so: 23*3+1= 70. And the process should start again, 70/2 = 35 then 35*3+1 = 106... And so on till it reaches the number one... :)

Comment: Mark, it doesn't reach the number one, because you increase the value by a factor. Look, here are the numbers: `15 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 80 241 120 361 180 541 270 811 405 1216 608 1825 912 2737 1368 4105 2052 6157 3078 9235 4617 13852 6926 20779 10389 31168 15584 46753 23376 70129 35064 105193 52596 157789 78894 236683 118341 355024 177512 532537 266268 798805 399402 ...`.

Comment: Yes you are right! How do I get it the function to get those results?

Comment: I added the snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(num):
    n = num
    l = list()
    while n>1:
        r = n/2
        l.append(r)
        n = r
    return [i*3+1 for i in l]
```

if I understand your question correctly this will solve

Answer (score 0):

I meant this and it works!:

```
def Gaus(n):   
    list = []
    list.append(n)
    if n > 0 and n == int(n): 
        while n != 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n/2
                list.append(n)
            else:
                n = (n*3)+1
                list.append(n)
        return list
    else:
        print "The given input number is not a natural number, try again!"
```